# Remove word from a meta value in mysql database

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress database and under my users meta data in their capabilities they each have assigned a few different capabilities and I would like to remove just

```
bbp_participant
```

from the meta_value table without removing the rest. The full line in the meta_value table is

```
a:2:{s:11:"contributor";b:1;s:15:"bbp_participant";b:1;}
```

[image: Database image]

You can see the full larger image here [Link to Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TluOc.png)

Edit:

For a little clarification right now in the meta value I have

```
a:2:{s:11:"contributor";b:1;s:15:"bbp_participant";b:1;}
```

I want to run a query to delete `s:15:"bbp_participant";b:1;`

So that the only thing that is remaining is `s:11:"contributor";b:1;`

Answer (score 1):

The basic format for this is a query like this:

```
update wp_usermeta t
    set meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'bbp_participant', '')
    where meta_value like '%bbp_participant%';
```

EDIT:

The type and length would presumably always be the same, so if you want to remove these:

```
update wp_usermeta t
    set meta_value = replace(meta_value, 's:15:"bbp_participant";', '')
    where meta_value like '%s:15:"bbp_participant";%';
```

Comment: you'll also need to remove the type and length identifier, ie, the preceding `s:15:`, as well as the surrounding `"`

Comment: @pala_ .  .  . That seems like a reasonable interpretation, but I'm going by what the question asks.  It is pretty clear about removing *just* the one string.

Comment: yeah it's php serialised data - if the associated data isn't removed, the de-serialisation will break.  the question is ambiguous on that at best, but even if the questioner doesn't realise this is what he needs, it really is

Comment: @pala_ . . . I give in.  Your interpretation is obviously the reasonable interpretation of what the OP really wants.  The type and length are presumably fixed, which makes this easy.

Comment: I did notice that I would need to remove all of 
s:15:"bbp_participant";b:1;

Comment: Why in the set meta vale do you have s:15:"bbp_participant";b:1; when I would like to delete it? shouldn't I leave that blank?  as I would only want s:11:"contributor";b:1; to remain

Comment: it's replace - he's replacing it with a blank string

Comment: and I would use update table wp_usermeta correct instead of update table t?

Comment: @Greenhoe . . . and you should probably also include `meta_key` in the `where` clause as well.